# Increase text of the dropdown menu - Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, interactive, ipywidgets

I am trying to create dropdown menu using the following code on Python.

```
pqrs = ['Segment1', 'Segment2', 'Segment3']

#Segment Criteria
Segment_selected = widgets.Text()
# print('=' * term_size.columns)
# print('\n' +"\033[1m" + 'Select a Segment criteria for Selecting HCP Universe' + "\033[0m")
# python code to run in jupyter notebook

from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, Layout
def lx(Segmentation):
    Segment_selected.value = str(Segmentation)
int_widget = interactive(lx, Segmentation=pqrs,)
int_widget.children[0].layout = Layout(width='400px',height = '40px')
display(int_widget)
```

This is generating the following output:
[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdR6V.png.)

Now, the problem is I want to show the complete text on the left side of the dropdown. It appears as "Segmentati..." in my case which I want it to be "Segmentation" in my case. But I am unable to do so.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially comments widths are fixed. You can set a style to make it bigger - this will reduce the overall other sizes of your widget:

```
pqrs = ['Segment1', 'Segment2', 'Segment3']

int_widget = interactive(lx, Segmentation=pqrs, )
int_widget.children[0].layout = Layout(width='auto',height = '40px')
int_widget.children[0].style = {'description_width': '200px'}  # increase size
display(int_widget)
```

to get:

[image: yupiter]

The essential documentation for this is [here: Widget Styling#Description](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#Description)

Try `"auto" or "initial"` for auto-fitting the `description_width`.

Comment: @Mufeez Now this should solve your problem - fiddle with the values.